# image url in AlertDialog in onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

This code is to open a dialog in OnPostExecute functions, and it works perfect.

The problem:

In the layout popup, which appears in the dialog, I have a imageview which I place him a URL to show me the picture of that url, the idea is to assign that url when creating the dialog, ie dynamically.

How could I do this?

Thanks for the help

```
@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                    //Toast.makeText(context, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    /*nombre.setText("");
                    dni.setText("");
                    telefono.setText("");
                    email.setText("");*/

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

                builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null))
                   .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              dialog.cancel();
                       }
                });


                builder.create();
                builder.show();




            }
```

Comment: Is your ImageView part of R.layout.popup?

Comment: Yes, the R.layout.popup contain the imageview

Comment: How do you plan to apply the URL on the ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `Dialog` layout View and the `ImageView` inside it before inflating it. Like this:

```
   //inside onPostExecute()
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
       LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
       View imageLayoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
       ImageView image = (ImageView) imageLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId);
       //an URI example
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/123");

       image.setImageURI(uri);

       builder.setView(imageLayoutView)
          .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     dialog.cancel();
              }
       });

       builder.create();
       builder.show();
```

Using this code, you set the `Uri` to the `ImageView` dynamically.